# Is there a way to Change how long the Xbox record time is?

Tags: xbox-one, recording

I am making a Xbox gameplay of bendy and the ink machine for my YouTube channel and I need the recording time last longer than 10minutes. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.thurrott.com/games/xbox-one/108449/xbox-one-tip-record-favorite-gameplay-moments) but it seems to indicate from the screenshots that the max length is only 5 minutes. So not sure if itll be helpful or not. (Disclaimer, I dont own an XB1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option on Xbox would be to use something like Mixer.  Mixer is installed by default, and has the option to record streams.  You will have to change your settings to enable a recording of the stream.

See https://windowsreport.com/save-mixer-streams-xbox/ for details on how to enable recording of your stream.

Answer (score 0):

To record longer than 10 minutes you are going to need a USB 3 hard drive or stick. Connect it to your Xbox, then go in to settings and change video recording from internal storage to external storage. Then you will be able to record up to 1 hour and it will be saved on the hard drive or stick.